# AngularJS app: How to properly implement authentication and authorization

Tags: angularjs, authentication, authorization, single-page-application

I have a requirements to implement a password-based local user authentication, and a role-based authorization in a new AnguletJS application. As a part of my requirements, user passwords must not be transmitted in a clear case from the client to server. Is there a standard way of implementing local user password-based authentication and role-based authorization in an Angular SPA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HTTPS and the password and username would be encrypted during the communication with the server. Here's a article that you might find useful: https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/7bbf0346acec